# Creating a web form using master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, master-pages

I have been doing this for hours and it keep coming out the same error. I don't know why ! I managed to create the first webform for masterpage. Somehow , subsequence webforms are getting the same error.

This is the webform i had created:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/EIDShopMain.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.WebForm3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

When i want to view it in browser:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.Global'.
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

**Update:** This is a ASP.Net Web Application Project.

Code-behind of WebForm3:

```
namespace mainWebsite_EID_Shop_
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : Page
    {
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why sometime the web form works and sometime it doesn't works.

**Update2:** More errors:

```
Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to  service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.EIDShopMain'.
Source Error:
Line 1: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EIDShopMain.master.cs" Inherits="mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.EIDShopMain" %>
Line 2:
Line 3: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;
```

Comment: Is it Web App project or Web Site project?

Comment: Also please post your code-behind file.

Comment: As you can see, the error is in Global.asax, not WebForm3.aspx

Comment: i don't remember having a Global.asax until you told me. I think is useless so i deleted them.... and now error again ! OMG.

Comment: What error do you have when deleted Global.asax.*?

Comment: Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.EIDShopMain'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EIDShopMain.master.cs" Inherits="mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.EIDShopMain" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: so sorry . I'm stuck at this. Just learned from a video which my school gave me the link .

Comment: mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.EIDShopMain means that it tries to load class EIDShopMain from namespace mainWebsite_EID_Shop. Looks like you don't have such, i.e. mismatch between markup and code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your Global.asax should look like the following:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="mainWebsite_EID_Shop_.Global" %>
```

and Global.asax.cs:

```
namespace mainWebsite_EID_Shop_
{
    public class Global
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. Ending namespace name with an underscore is definitely a bad design.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you about it being a bad design, but I seem to remember a situation causing visual studio to namespace pages like that by default (folder_folder) in web site projects.  It might have been when you convert a web site project to a web application project?  Or is just like that by default in web site projects?  Don't think I've ever chosen to use a web site project otherwise I could tell you more definitively ;).

Comment: @KennethIto: iirc, by default a code-behind file class called _Default for a web site project. Have never seen an auto-generated namespace ended by an underscore. I can be wrong still.

Comment: Just checked.  Made an asp.net 4 website project.  You won't see the underscore namespacing behavior unless your create pages in folders.  I created ~/TopLevelFolder/SecondLevelFolder/NestedPage.aspx and it generated the code behind as public partial class TopLevelFolder_SecondLevelFolder_NestedPage : System.Web.UI.Page.  I'm really not a fan of website projects.  Annnnd I just read this post and realized it's not applying the underscores to the namespace.  Just the class name.  Think you're totally right.